# Select box will not allow a selection UIWebView iOS9

Tags: javascript, html, uiwebview

I have a simple web page application that is acting weird with IOS9. The application uses UIWebview To access my website. I have series of webpages that have selection boxes, and when a selection is made, a little javascript will trigger and go to the next page. My Iphone users who have updated to ios9, are no longer able to select anything from the selection wheel. I was wonder if there is there is something I could change in html or Javascript to keep me from having to do entire application update.  My webpage is below.

```
<?
 include("conn.php");
 include("pl_header.php");

//// Get Block Areas

$sql="SELECT DISTINCT area FROM platform_locations";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$options="";

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $area=$row["area"];

$options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"search_step_2.php?area=$area\">".$area.'</option>';
}
?>



<h3>Step 1<br><br>Choose an Area</h3><br><br>

<form name=form1>

<select name="URL" onchange="$('#myLoadingPicture').show(); window.location.href=this.form.URL.options[this.form.URL.selectedIndex].value"    onfocus="javascript:toggle();" class="select">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Click Here To Select</option>
    <?=$options?>
    </SELECT>
<br><br><br><br>

<center>
<a href="map_search1.php" class="small_button">More Search Options</a></center><br>

</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the javascript (which is probably located in `pl_header.php`)? What exactly is the issue? Is the select disabled? Or does the website not load?

Comment: Hi, same here... The bug is really inside the "webview", not in safari. I created a simple web page, no css, no js, just a <select>, and I am unable to select it from inside the webview. Also, the "font" is really bigger when in the webview VS when in safari.    
I can select it in safari, but not in the webview.  
The selector opens, we can roll the selector, but impossible to "apply" the new value.

Answer (score 3):

The bug is only present inside UIwebview, on an iphone, using IOS 9.x.  It's ok on safari, and on ipad.  It's not a jquery or event handler issue.
It's a native select html tag issue.
We try to find a solution without recompile/submit our app to the store...
We have the bug when using the following very basic sample.

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>test ios9 bug</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>
  <select>
   <option>opt1</option>
   <option>opt2</option>
   <option selected="selected">opt3</option>
   <option>opt4</option>
   <option>opt5</option>
  </select>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Finally, we talked with our IOS team, and they need to recompile the native app, because the UIwebview we are using is not from ios 8, it's from ios7 or 6, (last store submission in august 2013), too old to be "backward compatible"... 
I suppose that people who have an app from the IOS 8 era doesn't have that issue.

Answer (score 2):

I've spend some time at testing your code. Your page works properly on the iOS 9 devices. Furthermore **[there were no changes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/RevisionHistory.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006950-CH2-SW1) in UIWebView class** that could cause this bug.

Looking at your question I'm not able to determine where is the bug.

---

Debugging tip:

Open the page you are viewing inside the UIWebView in the Safari on any iOS 9 device. UIWebView is based on the WebKit library that is also used in Safari so you will able to detect if the bug is in your iOS application or in a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of problems in iOS 9 (if you ask me it is broken). According to [this](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/8262) jQuery thread you can try the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.js">
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
      $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
   });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js">
```